# Can Apache FOP be used to produce PDFs that can keep PDF-Clients from scaling and changing orientation?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, apache-fop

i am using apache fop 1.0 to create some pdfs for customers for one of our clients. the printout of the pdf is read by a scanner later. Unfortunately the scanner cannot handle scaled printouts, so the question has come up if it might be possible to prevent scaling of a pdf in the pdf-client so that a printout would have to be done in the predefined size. I am aware of the possiblity of pdf-encryption which could be used to prevent printing at all, but what i need is somewhat different. So my questions are:

- is there a way to force the pdf-client to print a pdf in the defined size without scaling ?
- can the paper orientation be forced, too ?
- is this possible at all, can it be done with apache fop ?

Actually i do not think that it is possible, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

best regards

Tyler

Comment: Do you know what pdf client they are using?  And are you talking about the image scaling or the document itself?

Comment: no, unfortunately it could be any client. i'm looking for a way to prevent scaling and changing orientation of the whole document itself. Oh, and thank you for the quick response

Comment: I know you can set page layout in the xsl-fo tags but I don't think it is possible programmatically from the fop end to restrict what happens on the client side.    That would open up all kinds of security issues.   you can set scaling on images in the xsl-fo but I have never seen anything for the scale of the document as a whole.

Comment: I agree, thank you for the confirming words anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not really *control* the way a viewing application prints or displays a PDF. The best you can do is to attach a `ViewerPreferences` dictionary (section 12.2 of ISO 32000:2008) - but that's only a *hint* for the viewer.

Comment: Interesting, but it seems that apache fop does not support ViewerPreferences, at least i could not find some useful info googling for a few minutes, but i will take a kook at that later again. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @tyler, to attach ViewerPreferences use  [Does FOP 2.1 support viewer preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347687/does-fop-2-1-support-viewerpreferences/38381464#38381464)  (for FOP 2.1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FOP from the command line, you can look at `fop -out list` which presents the list of mime-types FOP will generate. See also [a FOP FAQ on output formats](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/output.html) , and **org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants** for a list of output formats you can generate programmatically.

To brevent re-sizeing, generating a raster (e.g., PNG or TIFF) output would help in this case. E.g., from the command line:

```
fop -xml data.xml -xsl transform.xslt -out "image/tiff" output.tiff
```

will generate a TIFF file. Use `"image/png"` for a PNG file, etc.

Programatically, you would, e.g.:

```
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
FOUserAgent userAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

TransformerFactory factory = org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Transformer transformer;

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(pdfOut[0].setBinaryStream(1L));

try {
  Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PNG /* or MIME_TIFF */, userAgent, out);
  transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltIn.getCharacterStream()));
  Source src = new StreamSource(xmlIn.getCharacterStream());
  Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
  transformer.transform(src, res);
} catch ...
```

Comment: (Avoiding of the) Scaling of the raster output would depend on the application with what you print it in just the same way as for pdf wouldn't it?