# Does FOP 2.1 support ViewerPreferences?

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using FOP 2.1 and am trying to set ViewerPreferences, e.g. DisplayDocTitle -> true.

I'm trying (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022931/how-to-resolve-displaydoctitle-key-is-not-set-to-true-error-generated-by-pac-t?s=1|1.3190)

```
<fo:declarations>
    <pdf:dictionary type="Catalog" xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache/org/fop/extensions/pdf">
        <pdf:dictionary type="normal" key="ViewerPreferences">
            <pdf:entry key="DisplayDocTitle" type="boolean">true</pdf:entry>
        </pdf:dictionary>
    </pdf:dictionary>
    <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
    ...
```

but getting

```
Jul 13, 2016 11:18:31 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Unknown formatting object "{http://xmlgraphics.apache/org/fop/extensions/pdf}dictionary" encountered (a child of fo:declarations}. (See position 242:105)
Jul 13, 2016 11:18:31 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Unknown formatting object "{http://xmlgraphics.apache/org/fop/extensions/pdf}dictionary" encountered (a child of dictionary}. (See position 243:69)
```

and no ViewerPreferences inside the pdf.

When I put the dictionarys below the `<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">` then I get no ViewerPreferences either, only pdfbox preflight will then complain about

```
The file test.pdf is not valid, error(s) :
7.3 : Error on MetaData, Cannot find a definition for the namespace http://xmlgraphics.apache/org/fop/extensions/pdf
```

What am I doing wrong, am I too early to try it? Where do I have to patch fop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [release notes](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/releaseNotes_2.0.html) FOP 2.0 introduced, among other things, a

> - Low level mechanism to augment PDF `/Catalog` and `/Page` dictionaries

but there are not many examples of its usage in the website.

Looking at the [testcases](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/tags/fop-2_1/test/layoutengine/standard-testcases/) included in the source distribution, in particular the ones named `pdf-dictionary-extension_*.xml`, I was able to put together something similar to your code which does not generate run-time exceptions; admittedly, I'm not familiar enough with this PDF feature to say whether the output actually achieves what you are trying to do:

```
<fo:declarations>
  <pdf:catalog xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf">
    <pdf:dictionary type="normal" key="ViewerPreferences">
      <pdf:boolean key="DisplayDocTitle">true</pdf:boolean>
    </pdf:dictionary>
  </pdf:catalog>
</fo:declarations>
```

- there is no `<pdf:dictionary type="Catalog">`, there is `pdf:catalog` instead
- there is not a single `<pdf:entry key="..." type="...">` element, but there is a specific element for each possible entry type: `pdf:array`, `pdf:boolean`, `pdf:name`, `pdf:number`, `pdf:string`, ...

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays)*

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot @ifurini ! So it is rather a documentation issue. The effect of these declarations is easy to make out - without them, acrobat reader displays the filename in the title bar, but when they work successfully, the Title of the document (set a few lines below in RDF / dc:title) is displayed

Answer (score 2):

As supplement to @lfurini's excellent finding, here are some more thing that can be done that way easily, tested with fop 2.1, but could also work from 2.0:, remove the comments from the relevant sections to try:

```
<fo:declarations>
  <pdf:catalog xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf">
    <!-- this opens in full-screen mode, e.g. as presentation -->
    <!-- pdf:name key="PageMode">FullScreen</pdf:name -->

    <!-- this opens then second page so it is fully visible -->
    <!-- (count seems to start at 0) -->
    <!-- pdf:array key="OpenAction">
      <pdf:number>1</pdf:number>
      <pdf:name>Fit</pdf:name>
    </pdf:array -->

    <!-- this will replace the window title from filename to below dc:title -->
    <pdf:dictionary type="normal" key="ViewerPreferences">
      <pdf:boolean key="DisplayDocTitle">true</pdf:boolean>
    </pdf:dictionary>
  </pdf:catalog>
  <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <!-- Dublin Core properties go here -->
        <dc:title>Sample Document title</dc:title>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </x:xmpmeta>
</fo:declarations>
```

Details of possible values can be looked up in the [pdf specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) (from page 139 in this v1.7 version, TABLE 3.25 Entries in the catalog dictionary), take care not to use values that would normally be set by fop anyway, restrict yourself to viewer/reader relevant stuff.